# Keyboard shortcut to type three backticks

Tags: shortcut-keys

Is there a way to add a keyboard shortcut to type three backticks?

*Background: I use these three backticks all the time in Slack, general markdown, Gitlab and it's annoying to have to press backtick followed by a space (German QWERTZ layout) three times at the beginning and at the end of every code block.*

I tried to add one with

````
xdotool type '```'
````

but it only adds backticks from time to time, mostly one or two, they seem to be "caught" by other programs that try to pair them with a vowel to be used as an accent.

I also tried with the `clearmodifiers` and  `delay` parameters with no success.

Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS + GNOME 3.28.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work more reliably if you paste from the clipboard. Besides `xdotool`, you need `xsel` or `xclip`.

**A oneliner** that you can directly bind to a shortcut key in Settings - Devices - Keyboard is:

```` sh -c "echo -n '```' | xsel -b -i && sleep 0.3 && xdotool key Control_L+v" ````

Alternatively, you can use **a small script** that also saves and restores the current textual clipboard contents.

````
#!/bin/bash
OLDSELECT="$(xsel --clipboard --input)"
echo -n '```' | xsel -b -i
sleep 0.3s
xdotool key  --delay 0 Control_L+v
echo "$OLDSELECT" | xsel  --clipboard --input
````

To bind the script to a shortcut key:

- Save the contents in a text file, e.g. ~/bin/backticks
- Make the file executable
- Bind it to a key by including the full pathname in the "Command" field of the "Set Custom Shortcut" dialog, e.g. `/home/$USER/bin/backticks`, where you substitute $USER by your actual login name.

Comment: On Kubuntu 18.04.1, I had to modify your one-liner to escape each backtick with "\".

Comment: @DKBose Strange, because it is the same shell on both systems. If you would remove the single quites, then you would need backslashes indeed, like `echo -n \\`\\`\\``

Comment: I'll check whether I used single or double quotes when I'm back in my Kubuntu install tomorrow.

Comment: I found a way to keep the clipboard's content with a hack of your solution (assuming the secondary is empty): `xsel -b | xsel -i -s && sleep 0.1 && echo -n '\`\`\`' | xsel -b -i && sleep 0.1 && xdotool key Control_L+v && xsel -s | xsel -i -b && echo | xsel -s`